# How to replace phpoffice/phpexcel with phpoffice/phpspreadsheet

Tags: laravel-5.5, maatwebsite-excel

Main error when doing `composer install`:

> Package phpoffice/phpexcel is abandoned, you should avoid using it.
>   Use phpoffice/phpspreadsheet instead.

I am using `"maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0"`
And `Laravel 5.5`

I wanna avoid migrating excel to 3.0. I already tried migrating it but it doesn't fit in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out the following guide, or the mentioned "Automated tool"

[Migration from PHPExcel](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/migration-from-PHPExcel/)

In the meantime, you can specify the complete version number of Excel to continue running updates.

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply. Yes I did this and it works! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*Discalimer: I wrote a tool that handles automated migration from CLI called Rector, so people don't have to upgrade PHP code manually anymore. [It's free, open-source, on GitHub](http://github.com/rectorphp/rector).*

Official "Automated tool" only fixes class names. There are 24 more cases, that needs to be changed. We need to upgrade huge PHP project and manual changes would take too much time and could stuck us for weeks.

Instead I made an **upgrade set with all 25 cases, that changed code for us**:

```
composer require rector/rector --dev
vendor/bin/rector process src --set phpexcel-to-phpspreadsheet
```

Do you want to **know more**? Check [How to Migrate From PHPExcel to PHPSpreadsheet with Rector in 30 minutes](https://getrector.com/blog/how-to-migrate-from-phpexcel-to-phpspreadsheet-with-rector-in-30-minutes) post